# Particles intersecting object and then exploding without reason

Tags: particles, add-on

**I'm using PyroEvil's Molecular Physics addon, which is required for the simulation to work. [Find it here.](http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-download/)**

I've been playing around with the aforementioned addon, to see what it can handle and what it can do. It's been producing some nice results, but I've been having some extremely strange behaviors with rotating objects. The particles somehow go inside it, and when it stops rotating everything just explodes outwards. Is there any way to fix this, or do I have to wait for a new release of the addon?

[Here's my blend file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/btjzohu3prk79pi/Sand%20test.blend?dl=1)

Comment: By the way, could someone with 150+ rep add a "molecular-physics-addon" tag or something similar?

Comment: It's a blender addon, question tagged addon, seems good to me. Molecular seems intersting, i'll check when i can.

Comment: @Poyoarya I think the addon tag is enough, having a new tag for every addon that may only get one or two questions isn't going to help. As for your question, it might be worth asking the developer directly.

Comment: centrifugal force could be the cause, if it's implemented. Don't hesitate to ask the dev on pyroevil.com and to post your own answer if you found something interesting :)

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-should-we-handle-questions-about-addons) and [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/464/are-questions-about-third-party-paid-addons-on-topic).

Comment: @PGmath OK, that's good :)